# Python poetry adding dependency to a group

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am using Poetry of version 1.3.2 (currently the last version), and added group to .toml file as below: `[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]`.

And following [official documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/managing-dependencies/#adding-a-dependency-to-a-group) tried to add library to this group using command:
`poetry add pytest --group dev`.

But always getting error that says: **The "--group" option does not exist**.

(Using python of version 3.9.15)

I tried to change version of poetry to 1.2.x, but it did not help.

Comment: Can you print version of poetry to be sure that you are using version that supports groups?

Comment: @LiuPiu ```Name: poetry
Version: 1.3.2
Summary: Python dependency management and packaging made easy.
Home-page: https://python-poetry.org/
Author: Sébastien Eustace
Author-email: sebastien@eustace.io
License: MIT```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just type:

```
poetry add --group dev 'package_name'
```

That should work